# Cохранить json локально для дальнейшей десериализации в android

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Приложению с сервера прилетает json, мне нужно его как-то сохранить в постоянную память, а потом достать для десериализации.

Comment: в базу данных (рекомендую Room Persistence Libary )в виде объекта или в shared preferences в виде строки

Comment: Если json один, либо их мало, либо они большие, то сохранять как файл.

Answer (score -2):

Если тебе нужно сохранить именно в постоянную память то вот как вариант:

```
String str = json.toString();
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences( "appData", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE );
SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = getSharedPreferences( "appData", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE ).edit();
prefEditor.putString( "json", str );
prefEditor.commit();
```

P.S. Я бы посоветовал использовать либо `Room` либо `Realm`